# Add Navigation Bar with title without Navigation controller on UITableViewController from Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

As my screen have static options, so I created a screen with static cells from `UITableViewController` class instead of `UIViewController`

Now When I'm trying to add the Navigation bar from storyboard it never adds above `UITableView`. Always added at the footer of the table view.

Can we add without programmatically?

Please refer screenshot:

[image]

Appreciate your help!

Thanks

Comment: You can't add any other views in UITableViewController. Why don't you want to use navigation controller?

Comment: Because of its only 2 screen app and no back n forth functionality required

Comment: You can embed the table view controller and don't use push from navigation controller.

Comment: yeah seems the only way to do.

Comment: Or you can create new view controller and add a navigation bar. Then add this tableview controller as child view controller. The first approach is best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Storyboard, you can't add any other view at the same level of the TableView in TableViewController, so adding UINavigationBar won't work here.

You can show navigation bar using UINavigationController:

1. In Storyboard first, select your **Table View Controller**.
2. Then Open **Editor menu**, and select **Embed In** option, and choose **Navigation Controller**. You will get your navigation controller pointing to your tableview controller.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you can embed your UiTableViewController in a UINavigationController from storyboard.

Just add a UINavigationController on the storyboard and drag to your UITableviewController and set it as either root or push.

You dont have to manually add the UINavigationBar.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is that you can embed your UITableViewController in a UINavigationController:

1. Select your UITableViewController in the Storyboard.
2. go to Editor => Embed In => Navigation Controller

The second solution is to add it programmatically, as you just said.